# How to show USED in the output of top?

Tags: top, virtual-memory

`top` doesn't show USED (a part of virtual memory) by default. How can I make it visible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>, then choose the display to order by memory usage by hitting key <kbd>n</kbd> then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You will see active process ordered by memory usage.

Or you can just press <kbd>M</kbd> after running the `top` command.

The command `top -o MEM` should work.